# Query InfluxDB 2.0 from R

Tags: r, influxdb, httr

I can retrieve the data with this query with Node-RED, but need to retrieve it with R.

This is as far as I've gotten.

```
post.1 <- httr::POST(url=paste0("http://", influx.ip, ":8086/api/v2/signin"),
                     authenticate(influx.user, influx.passwd))
# Authentication seems to work.

influx.query <- 'from(bucket: "nr_meas")
|> range(start: -12h)'

post.2 <- httr::POST(url=paste0("http://", influx.ip, ":8086/api/v2/query"),
                   query=list(org=influx.org),
                   add_headers("Content-Type: application/json",
                               'Accept: application/csv'),
                   body=list(q=influx.query)
                   )
content(post.2)
# $code
# [1] "invalid"
#
# $message
# [1] "failed to decode request body: invalid character '-' in numeric literal"
```

To save from Node-RED isn't an option (on different computer).

What is the right way to get data from InfluxDB to R?

Comment: I'm not an influx user, but I would expect the same authentication done in `post.1` would need to be used in the second query. There is no shared "session" between the two calls to `POST`. Try adding your `authenticate(..)` to your second call, or look at https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/api for the use of authentication tokens.

Comment: Thanks for tip. I just tried that, and also add_headers(paste0("Authorization: Token ", influx.token)), but same error is generated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try InfluxDB 2.0 [R client](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-r):

```
library(influxdbclient)

client <- InfluxDBClient$new(
    url = paste0("http://", influx.ip, ":8086"),
    token = "my-token",
    org = influx.org)
                        
data <- client$query('from(bucket: "nr_meas") |> range(start: -12h) |> drop(columns: ["_start", "_stop"])')
```